# How to Re-issue let's encrypt when new subdomains/mutiple domains added for Trafik on docker and also config refactoring

Tags: docker-compose, refactoring, lets-encrypt, traefik, code-readability

1. My previous effort to add additional domain was just to do

   - docker-compose down
   - remove the acme.json file
   - add another section in traefik.toml for the new domain
   - docker-compose up -d
   - new acme.json was generated

Now the problem is I tried the same procedure and it failed,
the acme.json file, if I delete the file and do docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d it is created as a directory

Also, I want to add new subdomains, for some reason only www is being available in the certificate. Can someone check my configs and see where I made mistake?

What is a good approach to drop current certificates for our domain and re-issue new certificate having additional subdomains?

2. And while here, how to refactor the `traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix` labels in own config file, cause they are hard to maintain?

In the docker composer base directory I got a directory called traefik/ for the same service having a Trafik docker image.

## traefik.toml

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
domain = 'mydomain.mk'
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "info@mydomain.mk"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
main = "*.mydomain.mk"
sans = ["mydomain.mk", "www.mydomain.mk", "api.mydomain.mk", "beta.mydomain.mk"]


[[acme.domains]]
main = "*.mydomain.de"
sans = ["mydomain.de", "www.mydomain.de", "api.mydomain.de", "beta.mydomain.de"]
```

## acme.json

```
    {
      "Account": {
        "Email": "info@mydomain.mk",
        "Registration": {
          "body": {
            "status": "valid",
            "contact": [
              "mailto:info@mydomain.mk"
            ]
          },
          "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/50006191"
        },
        "PrivateKey": "base64 excerpt...",
        "KeyType": "4096"
      },
      "Certificates": [
        {
          "Domain": {
            "Main": "mydomain.mk",
            "SANs": [
              "www.mydomain.mk"
            ]
          },
          "Certificate": "base64 excerpt...",
          "Key": "base64 excerpt...
        },
        {
          "Domain": {
            "Main": "mydomain.de",
            "SANs": [
              "www.mydomain.de"
            ]
          },
          "Certificate": "base64 excerpt...",
          "Key": "base64 excerpt..."
        }
      ],
      "HTTPChallenges": {},
      "TLSChallenges": null
    }
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command:
        --accessLog.filePath="/logs/access.log" \
        --acme.storage=/acme.json --logLevel=debug \
        ${TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINT_HTTP} ${TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINT_HTTPS} \
        --defaultentrypoints=${TRAEFIK_DEFAULT_ENTRYPOINTS} \
        --acme=${ACME_ENABLE} --acme.entrypoint=https --acme.httpchallenge --acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http \
        --acme.domains="${ACME_DOMAINS}" --acme.email="${ACME_EMAIL}" \
        --docker --docker.domain="${DOCKER_DOMAIN}" --docker.endpoint="unix:///var/run/docker.sock" \
        --docker.watch=true --docker.exposedbydefault="true"
    ports:
      - "${EDGE_PORT:-80:80}"           # The HTTP port
      - "${EDGES_PORT:-443:443}"        # The HTTPS port
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
      - router-logs:/logs
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.allowedHosts=www.mydomain.mk,mydomain.mk,www.mydomain.de,mydomain.de,${ADDITIONAL_HOSTS}"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"

    restart: on-failure
  service1:
      image: '${DOCKER_REGISTRY:-mydomain.mk:5000/}${SERVICE1_IMG:-service1:latest}'
      labels:
          - "traefik.port=80"
          - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https,http"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/v/,/v/dashboard,/v/dashboard/"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/v/,/v/dashboard,/v/dashboard/"
          - "traefik.frontend.headers.allowedHosts=www.mydomain.mk,mydomain.mk,www.mydomain.de,mydomain.de,${ADDITIONAL_HOSTS}"
          - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
```

## .env file content

```
EDGE_PORT=80:80
EDGES_PORT=443:443

# This will allow local development or new domains
# ADDITIONAL_HOSTS=

# ACME
ACME_ENABLE=true
ACME_EMAIL=info@mydomain.mk
ACME_DOMAINS=mydomain.mk,www.mydomain.mk,mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de

DOCKER_DOMAIN=mydomain.mk

TRAEFIK_DEFAULT_ENTRYPOINTS=http
TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINT_HTTP=--entryPoints="Name:http Address::80"
TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINT_HTTPS=--entryPoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS"
TRAEFIK_HOST=mydomain.mk,www.mydomain.mk,mydomain.de,www.mydomain.de
```